# Загрузка кода символа через fstream

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

Возможно ли через поток загрузить число из файла в переменную типа char, не как символ, а как код символа?
Строка в файле:

```
11  8000    5 09:00:10  3
```

код

```
char a;
... 
fstream fp;
fp.open("C:\\t.txt",std::ios_base::in);
while (!fp.eof()) {
    fp>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;
};
```

нужно чтобы после этой операции: a = 11, сейчас же он читает а = '1'

Comment: не стоит говорить про: int x; fp>>x>>b>>c>>d>>e; a=x; хочется более лаконично

Comment: fp>>int(a)>>b>>c>>d>>e; - дает ошибку компиляции, это уже пробовал

Comment: Ну, для little endian (например, x86) можно извратиться через fscanf (конечно, это FILE \*, а не fstream)

Comment: Прочитать 2 символа + atoi()?

Comment: Нет. Наложить нужное число int \* a, int \*b, ...  на эти char (или  на байты char[] (*последовательно!!!*), если формируем строку) и вызвать fscanf("%d %d ..."...) . Поскольку 8 значащих (интересующих нас как код символа) бит будут в младшем байте, а scanf работает слева направо, то все получится одним вызовом (маленькая магия на машинном уровне)

Answer (score 1):

Если не хочется объявлять отдельно переменную другого типа, а хочется лаконичности, тогда придётся добавить немного вспомогательного кода, который это будет делать на автомате. Вот один из вариантов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct MagicChar
{
    MagicChar(char& symbol):
        m_Symbol{symbol}
    {
    }
    char& m_Symbol;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& strm, MagicChar symb)
{
    int symbolCode = 0;
    strm >> symbolCode;
    symb.m_Symbol = static_cast<char>(symbolCode);
    return strm;
}

int main()
{
    char symbol = 0;
    fstream fp;
    fp.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    fp >> MagicChar(symbol);
    std::cout << symbol << std::endl;
}
```

Или можно не плодить сущностей, а использовать существующие:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& strm, std::reference_wrapper<char> symb)
{
    int symbolCode = 0;
    strm >> symbolCode;
    symb.get() = static_cast<char>(symbolCode);
    return strm;
}

int main()
{
    char symbol = 0;
    fstream fp;
    fp.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    fp >> std::ref(symbol);
    std::cout << symbol << std::endl;
}
```

P.S. `test.txt` содержит число 11 и больше ничего